# Can we take a supremum over all Hilbert spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, lo.logic, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-philosophy

In my paper [On the optimal error bound for the first step in the method of cyclic alternating projections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00531), I defined functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$,
$n\geqslant 2$, by
$$
f_n(c)=\sup\{\|P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\|\,|\,c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c\},
$$
where

(1) the supremum is taken over all complex Hilbert spaces $H$ and systems of closed subspaces $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ of $H$ such that the Friedrichs number $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)$ is less than or equal to $c$. The Friedrichs number is a quantitative characteristics of a system of closed subspaces,
$c$ is a given number from $[0,1]$.

(2) $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H_i$, $i=1,2,\dotsc,n$ and $P_0$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $H_1\cap H_2\cap\dotsb\cap H_n$.

**Now I have some doubts in the validity of this definition.**
Namely, I know that all sets do not constitute a set and if I understand things right, all Hilbert spaces do not constitute a set (and even all one dimensional Hilbert spaces do not constitute a set). **So, can I take the supremum?**

**Please help me; I will be very grateful for any comments, remarks, and answers.**

In response to Mike Miller's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces#comment952651_375759):
Unfortunately, I also know almost nothing about set theory.
Yes, I understand that in fact I take the supremum of a "set" of real numbers, namely, of the "set" $A=A_n(c)$
which consists of all $a\in\mathbb{R}$
for which there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed
subspaces $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ of $H$ such that $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c$ and
$\|P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\|=a$.
**But I do not understand why the "set" $A$ is a set.**

Comment: I do not know anything about the context and almost nothing about set theory. But you are not taking the supremum over a `set' of Hilbert spaces and collections of subspaces. Rather, from all of those Hilbert spaces, you produce a set of real numbers, and you take the supremum of that set. No issue there: subclasses of sets are sets.

Comment: Dear Mike Miller, thank you for your comment. I edited the question.

Comment: I guess you should first label the cardinalities of the basis for each hilbert space. Let's just have $\kappa$ be the cardinality of H which is certainly bigger than the size of a basis. Each collection of hilbert spaces can be described by an onb for each hilbert space. Wouldn't the cardinality of this set you defined be smaller than the cardinality of $\kappa^{\kappa^n}$?

Comment: The set $A$ is a set because it consists only of real numbers, and the real numbers form a set.

Comment: @MichaelMontgomery. In the definition of the function $f_n$ a Hilbert space $H$ is **arbitrary**, so we can not bound the Hilbert dimension of $H$.

Comment: @MichaelMontgomery, since it appears that the question wants to distinguish among isomorphic Hilbert spaces, bounding by dimension won't work; as the question says, if we don't distinguish among isomorphic Hilbert spaces, even the class of one-dimensional Hilbert spaces is not a set.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, the "set" $A$ consists only of real numbers and $\mathbb{R}$ is a set. But I do not understand why these facts imply that $A$ is a set.

Comment: An example from operator algebras rather than operator theory: given a star-algebra $A_0$, one sometimes seeks to define a "maximal" Cstar-envelope of $A_0$ by defining a seminorm $\Vert a\Vert = \sup\{ \Vert \pi(a) \Vert\}$ where the supremum is taken over all star-representations of $A_0$ on all possible Hilbert spaces. Once again, one is referring to a proper class of objects, but one is only looking at a set of real numbers, and hence the definition above can be used safely

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko Because Separation says exactly that any time you can define (via a first-order formula) a collection of elements of a set, that collection is itself a set. We have a definition of $A$ (never mind how complex it is) and a set within which $A$ lives (namely, $\mathbb{R}$), so we get that $A$ is a set.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is true that we cannot use an arbitrary property$^1$ $P$ to define a set, in the sense that the collection of **all** things with property $P$ need not be a set. However, the [axiom (scheme) of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) says that we **can** use an arbitrary property to define a *subset*: whenever $X$ is a set, the collection $\{x\in X: P(x)\}$ is also a set.

So just take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $P(x)$ = "There is a Hilbert space such that …". Per Separation, we get that your collection of reals $A$ is in fact a set. And we may now take its supremum.

Note that this illustrates an important point about how $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (and its variants) get around Russell's paradox:

> It's **size**,$^{2}$ not **complexity of definition**, which controls whether or not a collection is a set or a proper class in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.$^{3}$

Part of the success of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is due to the ease with which we can in fact verify that something is a set. The only time you'll run into trouble is when you want to form a set which isn't a priori part of some bigger thing you already know is a set; here we may have to think a bit (although the [axiom (scheme) of *replacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) similarly makes things usually very easy, once it's mastered).

---

EDIT: Per the [comments below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces#comment953257_375762), let me sketch how to define "complete metric space" in the language of set theory. As you'll see, even the sketch is quite lengthy; if there's a particular point you'd like further information on, I suggest asking a separate question at MSE.

Here's the sequence of definitions we need to whip up:

1. We need to talk about ordered pairs, functions, and Cartesian products.
2. We need to build $\mathbb{N}$, so that we can build $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}$, so that we can build $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$; along the way we'll need the notions of equivalence relation and equivalence class, of course.
3. While the previous two points will be enough to define metric spaces ("An ordered pair $(X,\delta)$ where $X$ is a set and $\delta:X^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that [stuff]"), to define *complete* metric spaces we'll also need the notions of **infinite sequence** and **equivalence relation/class**.

The first bulletpoint is standard set-theoretic fare which you'll see treated in the beginning of any text on set theory, so I'll skip it; if you're interested, though, you can start with [the wiki page on ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair).

The third is really the first in disguise: an infinite sequence is just a function with domain $\mathbb{N}$.

So all the "meat" is in bulletpoint 2. We proceed as follows:

- First, we'll use the von Neumann approach to $\mathbb{N}$: an *ordinal* is a hereditarily transitive set, ordinals are ordered by $\in$, and the finite ordinals are the ordinals which do not contain any (nonempty) limit ordinal. We then identify $\mathbb{N}$ with the finite ordinals — more jargonily, $\mathbb{N}=\omega$. We define addition and multiplication of ordinals via transfinite recursion as usual.
- Next, we consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\omega\times(\omega\setminus\{0\})$ as follows: $$\langle a,b\rangle\sim\langle c,d\rangle \iff ad=bc,$$ and we let $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge0}$ be the set of $\sim$-classes. We lift the ordering on $\omega$ to $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}$ in the obvious way.
- Now we're ready to define $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, via Dedekind cuts: an element of $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is a nonempty, downwards-closed, bounded-above subset of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge0}$. The ordering on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is just $\subseteq$.

With all this in hand, the naive definitions of metric space, Cauchy sequence, and complete metric space translate into the language of set theory directly (if tediously). The point is that all of this is first-order *in set theory*, with axioms like Powerset (which, despite what they mean intuitively, are indeed first-order) doing the heavy lifting needed to show that the objects we want actually exist at all. (For a bit more about the nuance of "first-order in set theory," see [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3898216/28111).)

---

$^1$Really I mean "first-order formula," but I don't want to get too much into the details.

$^{2}$Specifically, in a precise sense we have: a class is a proper class iff it surjects onto the class of ordinals. This is not the same as the [principle of limitation of size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size), but it's of similar flavor.

$^3$I should observe that this isn't the only possible response to the need to distinguish between sets and proper classes: there are other set theories (e.g. $\mathsf{NF}$, $\mathsf{GPK^+_\infty}$, ...) which take the other approach. However, these theories make it harder to check whether something is in fact a set.

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to say something about using separation vs replacement here. The reason to be suspicious here is, in my view, that at first glance this looks like using replacement makes sense, and that is then thwarthed by $\mathcal{C}$ being a proper class.

Comment: @Arno I don't see how replacement is relevant here. The naive definition of $A$ literally is as a definable subclass of a given set - that's just separation. Where does replacement come in?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'd say that the initial definition of $A$ is as the image of $\mathcal{C}$ under a mapping. If $\mathcal{C}$ were a set, then using replacement to prove that $A$ is a set, too, seems more intuitive to me than starting to bring $\mathbb{R}$ into the picture and use separation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah Schweber, thank you for your answer. Due to my little knowledge of set theory, I am worried about the following. In the property $P(x)=$ "There exist a Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=x$" we use a Hilbert space $H$ which can be **arbitrary**, and we know that all Hilbert spaces do not constitute a set. Is this normal? Is property P allowed to use a class (which is not a set) in its definition?

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko No, that's not a problem: the axiom of separation says that **any** formula can be used to define a subset of a given set. "Use a proper class in its definition" makes things sound more mysterious than they are: what it really does is involve quantification over the whole universe, but that's just something "$\forall$" and "$\exists$" do by default.

Comment: @Arno Why? $\mathbb{R}$'s *already* in the picture: the thing $A$ we want is explicitly a collection of reals, hence a subcollection of a thing we already know is a set. (Besides, given the logical strength of Replacement I think it's better to use Separation when it will suffice.)

Comment: I deleted my comments since they were obviously creating unnecessary discussion, and I definitely did not mean them to be serious criticism (and I would think that's clear from my answer). In any case, I think my comment had the desired effect, as Noah expanded on his answer and made mine superfluous.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah Schweber, I have one more question. We have the property $P(x)$ of a real number $x$, namely, $P(x)=$"There exist a Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=x$". We want to use the axiom of separation. Question 1: to use the axiom we have to know that $P(x)$ can be represented by the first-order formula. Am I right? Question 2: If the answer to Question 1 is positive, why $P(x)$ can be represented by the first-order formula? I will be very very grateful for detailed answer.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko Your (1) is correct, but with an important caveat - $P$ needs to be a first-order formula **of set theory**. The domain of discourse in question is the whole universe, so - even though our logic is first-order! - we can quantify over sets, sets-of-sets, etc. (Perhaps it may help to think of this as using first-order *language* to describe a high-order context.) So what we need to do is show how to "code" all the relevant objects and properties - sequences, vector spaces, norms, topologies, closedness, etc. - by sets in an appropriate way. This is tedious, but not hard. (cont'd)

Comment: Basically, we take the usual natural-language definition and unpack it carefully. A heavy mover here is the set-theoretic implementation of [ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair) (and so of arbitrary functions and arbitrary-indexed Cartesian products). This lets us define for example an abelian group as a pair $\langle G,*\rangle$ where $G$ is a nonempty set, $*$ is a set of ordered triples of elements of $G$ (thought of as the *graph of* the group operation), and certain properties are satisfied. "Is a *(set coding a)* group" is then first-order expressible in set theory.

Comment: There are also a couple "starting tricks," like the von Neumann implementation of the natural numbers (and von Neumann ordinals in general). Ultimately with some practice **anything** you can describe in natural language is first-order definable in the universe of sets. Note that the context - "in the universe of sets" - is absolutely crucial here. First-order logic is only as strong as its ambient context: there is a first-order formula $\varphi$ in the language of set theory which, in the universe of sets, names exactly the (sets coding) finite groups, but by the compactness theorem (cont'd)

Comment: there is no first-order sentence $\psi$ in the language of groups which is satisfied in exactly the finite groups. The difference is that $\varphi$ is allowed to "use" the whole power of the entire set-theoretic universe, while a putative $\psi$ has to somehow "work just within the group itself." We generally emphasize the *weaknesses* of FOL at the beginning of logic classes, but when thinking about set theory we should really focus on its *strength* (except sometimes :P).

Comment: So tl;dr, actually writing out a first-order formula corresponding to the property you want would be very tedious but not conceptually difficult. I'm at a crossroads here; I do want to write **something** out in my answer since I think just handwaving my way through it is silly, but I don't have the kind of time needed to do the whole property. Is there something simpler you'd like to see? Maybe how in a first-order way we can define "complete metric space" or something similar?

Comment: This is the right answer (unbounded separation). But when you say it is the size, rather than the complexity of the definition that matters, there's an important exception. Consider a function $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow 2$ that maps Gödel numbers of true sentences to $1$ and false sentences to $0$. This is a countable set. If size were all there were to it, we would be able to prove that this function exists, but we can't (Tarski's undefinability theorem). But for each (external, standard) $n$, we can define such a function restricted to sentences with at most $n$ alternating quantifiers.

Comment: @RobertFurber, in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces#comment953015_375762), what is "this" in "This is a countable set"?  Is it the putative function $\mathbb N \to 2$?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, every function whose domain is a countable set is a countable set (of pairs). Maybe I should have said "this would be a countable subset of $\mathbb{N} \times 2$", but I was running short on characters.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah Schweber, thank you for your excellent comments and kind attention to my questions. I would like to see how in a first-order way we can define "Is a complex Hilbert space". But if this is tedious, "Is a complete metric space" will be sufficient for me.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko See my edit. Even complete metric spaces are *extremely* tedious. The language of set theory is not efficient at all - but with a bit of practice, it will become quite clear that it is sufficiently expressive.

Comment: I think you want your $\sim$ only on $\omega^2 \setminus \omega \times \{0\}$ (may I puckishly write $\omega \times 1$?), or else you get lots of fake rationals.

Comment: @LSpice Fixed (I went with $\omega\times(\omega\setminus\{0\})$ instead).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah Schweber, thank you for the edit, it was helpful for me. Now I have the following question (maybe silly, but really important for me; **it is the core of my worries**). In the example "Is an abelian group" above the corresponding first-order formula begins with "a pair $\langle G,\ast\rangle$, where $G$ is a nonempty set...". Similarly, in the example "Is a metric space" above the corresponding first-order formula begins with "An ordered pair $(X,\delta)$, where $X$ is a set...". (to be continued)

Comment: @NoahSchweber **Question**: Is it allowed for the first-order formula in the language of set theory to use the expression "X is a set" (meaning that X is **arbitrary** set)? I worry about this because all sets do not constitute a set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah Schweber, can you suggest me good literature about first-order formulas of set theory (for beginners) please?

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of this answer is to recall that the classical proof of the existence of suprema of bounded families of reals (as found in any analysis textbook) continues to work without any modifications whatsoever for proper classes.  (In particular, we do not assume that the existence of suprema of bounded nonempty subsets of reals has been proved yet.)

In fact, the proof works in the Zermelo set theory,
without the axiom of replacement and the axiom of choice.

**Theorem.**
Suppose $C$ is a nonempty class (possibly proper) and $g\colon C\to \mathbf R$ is a map bounded from above.
Then $\sup_{c\in C} g(c)$ exists.

*Proof.*
Denote by $U$ the set of upper bounds for $g$,
i.e., $U=\{u\in\mathbf R\mid \forall c\in C\colon g(c)\le u\}$,
which exists by the axiom of separation.

Since $\sup_{c\in C} g(c)$ is by definition the smallest upper bound for $g$,
we have to show that $U$ has the smallest element.
By assumption, $U$ is nonempty.
Since $C$ is nonempty, the set $U$ is bounded from below,
namely, it is bounded from below by $g(c)$ for any $c\in C$.
Thus, $U$ is a nonempty upward-closed subset of reals bounded from below,
i.e., an upper Dedekind cut, so $\inf U$ exists.
It remains to show that $\inf U \in U$.

Indeed, $\inf U \in U$ is equivalent to
$$\forall c\in C\colon g(c) \le\inf U,$$
which in its turn (by definition of $\inf$) is equivalent to
$$\forall c\in C \forall u\in U\colon g(c) \le u,$$
equivalently,
$$\forall u\in U \forall c\in C\colon g(c) \le u,$$
i.e.,
$$\forall u\in U\colon u\in U,$$
which is tautologically true.
Thus, $\inf U \in U$, so $\inf U$ is the smallest upper bound for $g$, which, therefore, exists.

Comment: More directly, use separation to show that the image of $g$, $I=\{u\in\mathbb R:\exists c\in C\,g(c)=u\}$, is a set, and then $\sup_{c\in C}g(c)=\sup I$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: More directly than what?  How do you show that sup I exists in your proof?  Note that inf U exists because U is an upper Dedekind cut.

Comment: sup $I$ exists because $I$ is a nonempty, bounded-above subset of the reals. The point being that you don't have to reexamine the proof to check whether it works for class-sized families; instead you can immediately reduce to the standard fact (and not care about how it was proved).

Comment: @ReidBarton: This is already indicated in the other answer, so I see no point in duplicating it here.  The point of this answer is that the classical proof works just fine for proper classes, without any modifications.