# Can we choose an element from a class?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, mathematical-philosophy

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $H_1,...,H_n$ be closed subspaces of $H$.
Set $H_0:=H_1\cap H_2\cap...\cap H_n$ and let
$P_i$ be the orthogonal projection onto $H_i$, $i=0,1,2,...,n$.
I study the functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f_n(c)=\sup\{\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|\,|\,
c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c\},\,c\in[0,1],
$$
where the supremum is taken over all complex Hilbert spaces $H$ and
systems of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$
for which the Friedrichs number $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)$ is less than or equal to $c$
(the Friedrichs number is a certain numerical characteristics of a system of subspaces).
Note that all such systems of subspaces **do not** form a set.
Despite of this, the function $f_n$ is well-defined
(see my Question [Can we take a supremum over all Hilbert spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces)).
Indeed, let $A_{n}(c)$ be the set of all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$ such that
$c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=a$.
Then by the axiom (scheme) of separation $A_{n}(c)$ is a **set** and thus we can take its supremum.

I need to show that $f_n(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$ for some function $g_n$.
I argue as follows.
Consider arbitrary element $a\in A_{n}(c)$.
Then there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$
such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=a$.
After this I work with this system of subspaces $(H;H_1,...,H_n)$ and show that
$\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|\leqslant g_n(c)$.
Thus $a\leqslant g_n(c)$.
Since this inequality holds for every $a\in A_{n}(c)$, we conclude that
$\sup A_{n}(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$, i.e., $f_n(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$.

**Questions.** Are all these arguments correct, say, in the axiomatic theory ZFC?
I am suspicious here because we need to choose an element (system of subspaces)
from a class (and work with this element).
Do we need here something like the Axiom of Choice?

In response to Nate Eldredge's comment: essentially, the core of my worries is the following. Unfortunately, and this is the worst, is that I do not understand if the **function** $A_n(c)\ni a\mapsto (H;H_1,...,H_n)$
such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=a$,
is needed in the arguments above or not.

Please help me.

Comment: I think generically, the question is as follows?  You have a first-order formula $\varphi(x,y)$, with $x,y$ free, and a set $A$ (maybe $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ here), and you can prove $\forall x \in A \: \exists y \: \varphi(x,y)$.  You would like to conclude there exists a function $f : A \to B$, where $B$ is some set, such that $\varphi(a, f(a))$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Unfortunately, and this is the worst, is that I do not really understand if the function is needed here or not.

Answer (score 4):

It is often tempting to think that all our existential instantiations happen "in advance", a sort of proof theoretic "mise en place" if you will.

But they don't, and they don't have to be. For a given $a$, we pick some $H$ and $H_i$'s, and so on. At each step, we only need to instantiate finitely many quantifiers.

Now, you may still wonder, how do we choose an element from a proper class? Well, the axiom of choice has absolutely nothing to do with that. As we know, a class is really a formula, i.e. $C$ is a class when there's some $\varphi(x)$ which defines it (we allow parameters, but I'm omitting them as they are fixed through this discussion anyway). To say that $C$ is not empty is exactly to say that $\exists x\,\varphi(x)$ holds. Now apply existential instantiation and we're done.

Even if you want to choose infinitely many elements from a class, which the above reasoning doesn't allow you, we can easily prove in $\sf ZF$ that no class is finite, and so that every class must contain an infinite set: simply look at $C\cap V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th step of the von Neumann hierarchy. Since we must add new elements unboundedly often, there is some $\alpha$ such that $C\cap V_\alpha$ is infinite. If we also assume choice, then we can even argue that we surpass every possible cardinality.

Comment: "But it's not, and it doesn't have to be" → "But they don't, and they don't have to be"?  (I love that _mise en place_ metaphor.)

Comment: I presume you mean "no *proper* class is finite".  (-:

Comment: @Mike: Obviously. :-)

Comment: @LSpice: It puts the saying "we're cooking up a proof" in a whole light.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf Karagila, thank you for your answer. Now I do not understand one point. Essentially, the core of my worries is the following. I do not understand if the **function** $A_n(c)\ni a\mapsto (H;H_1,...,H_n)$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_2 P_1-P_0\|=a$, is needed in my arguments above (in the question) or not.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: No. Fix $c,n,a$, then you know there is some $(H;H_i)$ for which the thing work. As I write, you don't have to choose everything in advance. Deal with your problems when they come up.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, assume that I fix $n,c,a$. Can I write $(H;H_1,...,H_n)=(H(a);H_1(a),...,H_n(a))$?

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: Can you? Sure. Will it be syntactically correct? Also yes. Will it be misleading for any reader who thinks that those are chosen in advance? Probably yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have a feeling that I do not understand something important...Ok, assume that I can write $(H(a);H_1(a),...,H_n(a))$. But then by similar arguments I can prove the Axiom of Choice: let $A_i, i\in I$ be a set of mutually disjoint nonempty sets. We will construct a transversal for this set as follows. Consider arbitrary $i\in I$ and **fix** it. Since $A_i$ is nonempty, $\exists x(i)\in A_i$. After this we consider one-element sets $\{x(i)\}$ and the set $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x(i)\}$. Then $A$ is a set and $A$ contains exactly one element in common with every $A_j$. To be continued

Comment: @Ivan: As I said, that would be *misleading to the reader*, apparently also for you. Just because you wrote $f(a)$ does not mean that it is *actually* define a function. It is a notation, it tells you that $f$ depends on $a$ and that it is fixed within a given context. That is all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thus $A$ is a needed transversal. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am lost in these arguments and the Axiom of Choice. I do not understand when we need a (choice) function and when we do not need a (choice) function. Can you suggest me a literature, please, so that I can understand the essence of these things?

Comment: @Ivan: You need to use AC when you *need* to choose things uniformly. When you just want to claim that something is independent of the choice, you can just pick representatives when necessary. Don't feel bad, it's confusing for **a lot** of mathematicians. You need time and practice to get used to it.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko To add to Asaf's comment, a good rule of thumb for when you need AC (or rather, when you *don't* need it) is: can you describe how you're making your choices in such a way that somebody else following that method would be **guaranteed** to produce the same objects? For example, if for each $a\in A$ there is *exactly one* $b\in B$ such that $\varphi(a,b)$ holds, then we can form the function $A\rightarrow B$ sending each $a$ to the corresponding $b$ without choice. (cont'd)

Comment: If however there may be multiple such $b$s, we don't (yet) have a choice-free argument for the existence of a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $\varphi(a,f(a))$ holds for all $a\in A$. (This is how [your AC argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080967) breaks.) Now there is a subtlety here: what exactly counts as a "description" of the above type? The answer is not quite simply "a first-order formula *with finitely many parameters*" (every model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$ satisfies *finite* choice *even if* $M$ has nonstandard naturals!), but that's a good approximation initially.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, I have one more question. Let $n$ be a natural number and $c,a$ be real numbers. Suppose that there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$ such that for some indices $i,j$ $H_i\neq H_j$ (the Friedrichs number is defined only for such systems of subspaces), $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|=a$. I need to choose such system of subspaces $(H;H_1,...,H_n)$ and work with this system. I understand that to do this I should use **existential instantiation**. To be continued.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this formally; I want to have precise formal arguments to do this. Please help me.