# Is a function needed here?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, mathematical-philosophy

This question is related to my question [Can we choose an element from a class?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387353/can-we-choose-an-element-from-a-class).
However, I decided to create a separate question.

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ be closed subspaces of $H$.
Set $H_0\mathrel{:=}H_1\cap H_2\cap\dotsb\cap H_n$ and let
$P_i$ be the orthogonal projection onto $H_i$, $i=0,1,2,\dotsc,n$.
I study the functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f_n(c)=\sup\{\lVert P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\rVert \mathrel|
c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c\},\,c\in[0,1],
$$
where the supremum is taken over all complex Hilbert spaces $H$ and
systems of closed subspaces $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ of $H$
for which the Friedrichs number $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)$ is less than or equal to $c$
(the Friedrichs number is a certain numerical characteristic of a system of subspaces).
Note that all such systems of subspaces **do not** form a set.
Despite this, the function $f_n$ is well-defined
(see my Question [Can we take a supremum over all Hilbert spaces?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces)).
Indeed, let $A_{n}(c)$ be the set of all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ of $H$ such that
$c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\lVert P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\rVert=a$.
Then by the axiom (scheme) of separation $A_{n}(c)$ is a **set** and thus we can take its supremum.

I need to show that $f_n(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$ for some function $g_n$.
I argue as follows.
Consider arbitrary element $a\in A_{n}(c)$.
Then there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and a system of closed subspaces $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$ of $H$
such that $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\lVert P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\rVert=a$.
After this I work with this system of subspaces $(H;H_1,\dotsc,H_n)$ and show that
$\|P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\|\leqslant g_n(c)$.
Thus $a\leqslant g_n(c)$.
Since this inequality holds for every $a\in A_{n}(c)$, we conclude that
$\sup A_{n}(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$, i.e., $f_n(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$.

**Questions.** Are all these arguments correct, say, in the axiomatic theory ZFC?
Essentially, the core of my worries is the following.
Unfortunately, I do not understand if the **function** $A_n(c)\ni a\mapsto (H;H_1,...,H_n)$
such that $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\lVert P_n\dotsm P_2 P_1-P_0\rVert=a$,
is needed in the arguments above or not.
If a function is needed here, it turns out that the "Axiom of Choice for classes" is needed here,
and I do not know what to do with this.
On the one hand, it seems that the function is not needed here.
On the other hand, we choose a system of subspaces for each $a\in A_n(c)$;
the set $A_n(c)$ can be infinite and we need to consider **all** $a\in A_n(c)$.
Therefore, perhaps, a function is needed here.
**Explain to me, please, whether a function is needed here or not?**

Please help me.

Comment: As in all your questions, you do not need the axiom of choice to choose *one* element from a non-empty class; that's what non-empty means.  You only need AC to make *many* choices simultaneously.  See, for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387353/can-we-choose-an-element-from-a-class#comment988193_387356 .

Comment: Also, a TeX note:  please do not use repeated periods to simulate dots; that's what the various `\dots` commands are for.  Compare the spacing in $H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \dotsb \cap H_n$ `H_1 \cap H_2 \cap \dotsb \cap H_n` to that in $H_1 \cap H_2 \cap ... \cap H_n$ `H_1 \cap H_2 \cap ... \cap H_n`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The answers are as follows: these arguments are correct, the indicated function is not needed.  Indeed, your argument might as well prove that for all H1,…,Hn, H such that c_F(H1,…,Hn)⩽c, you have  ∥Pn⋯P2P1−P0∥⩽g_n(c).  Quantifying over a collection of sets is perfectly legitimate even if this collection of sets forms a proper class.  There is no need to mention A_n(c) at all, it only creates further confusion.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Would you mind posting your comment as an answer to close out the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are as follows: these arguments are correct, the indicated function is not needed.

Indeed, your argument might as well prove that for all $H_1,\dotsc,H_n$, and $H$ such that $c_F(H_1,\dotsc,H_n)\le c$, you have $\lVert P_n\dotsm P_2P_1−P_0\rVert \le g_n(c)$.
Quantifying over a collection of sets is perfectly legitimate even if this collection of sets forms a proper class.
There is no need to mention the set $A_n(c)$ at all, it only creates further confusion.

Comment: Dear Dmitri, thank you for your answer. One thing is confusing for me. Assume that my arguments (proof of $f_n(c)\leqslant g_n(c)$) are correct. Then by "similar" arguments I can prove the Axiom of Choice. The "proof" is as follows. Let $A_i, i\in I$ be a set of mutually disjoint nonempty sets. We will construct a set that contains exactly one element in common with each of the sets as follows. Consider arbitrary $i\in I$ and **fix** it. Since the set $A_i$ is nonempty, $\exists x$ such that $x\in A_i$. To be continued.

Comment: Now we use the existential instantiation and write $x(i)$ for a new symbol (just a symbol) such that $x(i)\in A_i$. Consider one-element sets $\{x(i)\}$ and let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x(i)\}$. Then $A$ is a set and $A$ contains exactly one element in common with each $A_j$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko You go wrong as soon as you define $A$: intuitively this requires you to *"unfix"* your chosen element $i$. You'll see this if you sit down and try to write out your argument as a formal proof (say, in [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus)). Basically you have a first existential instantiation picking an $i$ and following that a second existential instantiation picking an $x$, but there isn't a logical rule letting you somehow "uniformize" this. (In fact you can think of $\mathsf{AC}$ as an additional logical rule in a precise, if technical, sense.)

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: Your argument is not similar.  In my answer, the statement is proved for all H_i and H.  In your comment, you have to choose x(i).  In particular, “existential instantiation” simply does not work in “families” as described; there is no such rule in first-order logic.  No such choices are made in my answer.  In particular, I do not choose H_i and H for each c, but rather prove the inequality for all H_i and H.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Dear Noah, thank you for your comment. I was desperate to find answers to my questions on the Axiom of Choice...So, if I understand you correctly, my mistake in my "proof" of the Axiom of Choice is that I need to consider all $x(i)$ simultaneously, and this cannot be done without the Axiom of Choice. Am I right?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Dear Dmitri, I think that the choice of $(H;H_1,\ldots,H_n)$ is implicitly present in your arguments. Indeed, we write $f_n(c)=\sup\{\|P_n\cdots P_2 P_1-P_0\|\,|\, c_F(H_1,\ldots,H_n)\leqslant c\}$, but the precise meaning of this formula is that $f_n(c)=\sup A_n(c)$, i.e., $f_n(c)$ is the supremum of a certain **set**. Now if we "unfold" your arguments, we will get essentially my arguments in the Question. So I think that the choice of $(H;H_1,\ldots,H_n)$ is necessary.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: No, the precise meaning of this formula is **not** what you wrote.  The supremum in this case is by definition the smallest number A≥0 such that ∥P_n⋯P_2P_1−P_0∥ ≤ A for all H_1, …, H_n, H such that c_F(H1,…,Hn)≤c.  Absolutely nothing in this definition requires the domain of quantifiers to be sets as opposed to proper classes, and I do not understand why you think they should be, or why you continue to insist on using A_n(c), which are **totally unnecessary**.  The supremum always exists.  In particular, there is no "unfolding" hidden here.

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: It appears that your insistence on using the auxiliary set A_n(c) may originate in one of the answers (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces/375762#375762) that was given here on MathOverflow.  I posted a new answer (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375759/can-we-take-a-supremum-over-all-hilbert-spaces/389947#389947) to the same question, which should make it clear that no such auxiliary sets are necessary.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Dear Dmitri, many thanks for your very helpful comments and answers to my questions. I have one more question. Now I see that $\sup\{\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\,|\,c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c\}$ can be defined in two different ways. The first way: the supremum is the smallest real number $u$ such that $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\leqslant u$ for all $H;H_1,...,H_n$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$. The second way: consider the set $A_n(c)$, then our supremum is $\sup A_n(c)$. These two definitions are equivalent. My arguments are as follows. (To be continued).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Let $U$ be the set of all real numbers $u$ such that $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\leqslant u$ for all $H;H_1,...,H_n$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$. We will show that the set of upper bounds for $A_n(c)$ equals $U$. Suppose that $u$ is an upper bound for $A_n(c)$. Consider arbitrary $H;H_1,...,H_n$ with $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$. Then $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\in A_n(c)$ and thus $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\leqslant u$. Thus $u\in U$. (To be continued.)

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Now suppose that $u$ is not an upper bound for $A_n(c)$. Then there exists $a\in A_n(c)$ such that $a>u$. For this $a$ there exist $H;H_1,...,H_n$ such that $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$ and $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|=a$. Thus $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|>u$. Thus $u\notin U$. It follows a real number $u$ is an upper bound for $A_n(c)$ if and only if $u\in U$, i.e., the set of upper bounds for $A_n(c)$ equals $U$. Then the minimal elements of the sets are equal, i.e., $\sup A_n(c)=\min U$.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thus we proved that two definitions of $\sup\{\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\,|\,c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c\}$ are **equivalent**. My question: I think that all arguments above are correct in ZF and I **did not** use the Axiom of Choice (I used only a few existential instantiations). Am I right?

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: Yes, absolutely.  In fact, the axiom of replacement was not used, so the proof works in the Zermelo set theory also.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Dear Dmitri, I have one more question. To define $\sup\{\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\,|\,c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c\}$ we have to consider the **set** $U$ of all real numbers $u$ such that $\|P_n...P_1-P_0\|\leqslant u$ for arbitrary Hilbert space $H$ and arbitrary system of closed subspaces $H_1,...,H_n$ of $H$ such that for some indices $i$ and $j$ $H_i\neq H_j$ (the Friedrichs number is defined only for such systems of subspaces) and $c_F(H_1,...,H_n)\leqslant c$. But why is $U$ a set? My argument: **$U$ is a set by the axiom (scheme) of separation**. Am I right?

Comment: @IvanFeshchenko: Yes, U is a set by separation: it is constructed as {u∈R| ...}, and ... can be any first-order formula, such as the one you used.